# Обособление определения, относящегося к личному местоимению

Tags: пунктуация, определения

У Розенталя сказано:

> Определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется
> независимо от степени его распространенности и местоположения:
> *Убаюканный сладкими надеждами, он крепко спал* (Ч.); *Низенький,
> коренастый, он обладал страшною силою в руках* (М. Г.); *Он повернулся и
> ушёл, а я, растерянный, остался рядом с девочкой в пустой жаркой степи*
> (Пауст.)

Тем не менее мне неоднократно попадались выражения типа *"Он повернулся и ушёл, а рядом с девочкой остался стоять растерянный я"*.
**Подобная конструкция — ошибка?**
Или здесь действует правило про связь со сказуемым?

> Не обособляется определение при личном местоимении:
> ...если определение по смыслу связано не только с
> подлежащим-местоимением, но и со сказуемым: *Я сидел
> погружённый в глубокую задумчивость* (П.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, хотелось бы посмотреть реальные примеры из художественной литературы, причем достаточно авторитетных авторов.

Это предложение по правилам нужно записать с обособлением, но и этот вариант не кажется стилистически корректным: *Он повернулся и ушёл, а рядом с девочкой остался стоять, **растерянный**, я.*

Но предположим, что автор намеренно не обособил определение: *Он повернулся и ушёл, а рядом с девочкой **остался стоять растерянный** // я.*

Тогда здесь сказуемое "остался стоять растерянный", но при этом главные члены инверсированные. И это надо обозначить при чтении, то есть сделать паузу перед местоимением "я".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134404/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).